# Extract tables from web page

Tags: r, rvest

#### The problem

I am trying to download the tables in the following web page:
https://www.ato.gov.au/Rates/Individual-income-tax-for-prior-years/

#### My attempt

```
read_html('https://www.ato.gov.au/Rates/Individual-income-tax-for-prior-years/') %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = '//tr//*[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 1) and parent::*)]') %>% 
  html_text()
```

The issue being that this code returns 639 rows of data. I would like for the imported data to maintain the something like the table structure it has on the web page (like a list of tables or even just one big dataframe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to keep them as list of dataframes and to distinguish the tables,  name them with the `caption` available

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.ato.gov.au/Rates/Individual-income-tax-for-prior-years/"
url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_table() %>%
  setNames(., url %>%
               read_html() %>%
              html_nodes("caption") %>%
              html_text())


#$`Resident tax rates for 2016-17`
#      Taxable income                         Tax on this income
#1        0 – $18,200                                        Nil
#2  $18,201 – $37,000               19c for each $1 over $18,200
#3  $37,001 – $87,000 $3,572 plus 32.5c for each $1 over $37,000
#4 $87,001 – $180,000  $19,822 plus 37c for each $1 over $87,000
#5  $180,001 and over $54,232 plus 45c for each $1 over $180,000

#$`Resident tax rates for 2015-16`
#      Taxable income                         Tax on this income
#1        0 – $18,200                                        Nil
#2  $18,201 – $37,000               19c for each $1 over $18,200
#3  $37,001 – $80,000 $3,572 plus 32.5c for each $1 over $37,000
#4 $80,001 – $180,000  $17,547 plus 37c for each $1 over $80,000
#5  $180,001 and over $54,547 plus 45c for each $1 over $180,000
#......
```

If you want it as one single dataframe, we can use `bind_rows` with `.id` parameter

```
url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_table() %>%
  setNames(., url %>%
              read_html() %>%
              html_nodes("caption") %>%
              html_text()) %>%
   bind_rows(.id = "id")
```